# How to change / replace the associated image of an icon located in the menu bar (BigSur)?

Tags: finder, big-sur, icon, menu-bar

I know how to change the icon of an application (.APP) with .ICNS (same method applies to folder and file icons), but how can I change the specific icon related to that app in the menu bar?

I have this [Unite](https://www.bzgapps.com/unite) app which convert websites into native macOS applications (.app based on WebKit). A cool feature is that, it can also create a menu bar icon which actually displays a website in their respective mobile version. The menu bar app/icon created in Unite, shows a horrible small image of the .ICNS/app, and I want to change that image with something in the style of actual macOS bar icons.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you talked to the the developer?  My understanding is that you can't modify icons in the menubar - the icons are part of the app.

Comment: Not yet, I was thinking you could change that icon image with some hardcore but quick method. Thank you.

Comment: Cant test right now, but I think if you open the App package and locate the `.icns` file (e.g. for Amphetamine its stored under `Contents`, `Resources`, you may be able to change that.

Comment: @X_841 You may be on to something. I looked at two apps with menubar icons - one has an `.icns` file and the other just a `.png`. So it will vary what to look for. Do you need to regenerate the checksums in `Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources`? If so, how?

Comment: @X_841 My discoveries are:

1. Reading the official Human Interface Guidelines from (https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/extensions/menu-bar-extras/) these things are officially called **"Menu Bar Extras"**.

2. I want to believe that you can change that icon from that "Menu Bar Extra" from the contents of the app package. Yeah, I discovered that those MBE icons should be in PNG format and that "light or dark icon mode" is in fact created by the system. MacOS automatically discards color information from that PNG, but I couldn't find more information.

Comment: @Gilby I'm still trying to figure it out:

3. This link https://8thlight.com/blog/casey-brant/2019/05/21/macos-menu-bar-extras.html) Is a condensed guide on how to create a Menu Bar Extra from Xcode. Pretty much of this info is out of my knowledge, but it may give some clues regarding the process and files linked to these "MBE".